# Updating Stripe Legal Entity with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am working on creating a form for my independent contractors to update their legal information for Stripe.

Currently, I have the following form:

**_legal_form.html.slim**

```
- entity = current_user.stripe_entity.legal_entity
- is_individual = (entity['type'] == 'individual')
- is_business = !is_individual
- business_name = entity['business_name'] || ""
- business_tax_id = entity['business_tax_id'] || ""

= form_tag legal_entity_payment_path(current_user), id: 'legal-form' do
.form-group 
    label for="type" = t('payments.legal.type')
    select id="type" class="form-control" onchange="showBusiness()"
        - if is_individual
            option value='business' = t('payments.legal.business')
            option value='individual' selected="selected" = t('payments.legal.individual')
        - else
            option value='business' selected="selected"= t('payments.legal.business')
            option value='individual' = t('payments.legal.individual')

.form-group id='business-fields' style="display:none"
    label for="business_name" = t('payments.legal.business_name')
    input id="business_name" type="text" class="form-control"  value=business_name

    label for="business_tax_id" = t('payments.legal.business_tax_id')
    input id="business_tax_id" type="text" class="form-control" value=business_tax_id

.form-group class="form-inline"
    .input-group
        label for="dob_month" = t('payments.legal.dob.month')
        input id="dob_month" type="number" class="form-control" value=entity.dob.month
    .input-group
        label for="dob_day" = t('payments.legal.dob.day')
        input id="dob_day" type="number" class="form-control" value=entity.dob.day
    .input-group
        label for="dob_year" = t('payments.legal.dob.year')
        input id="dob_year" type="number" class="form-control" value=entity.dob.year
    .input-group
        label for="ssn" = t('payments.legal.ssn')
        input id="ssn" type="number" class="form-control" value=entity.ssn_last_4_provided

.form-group
    label for="address" = t('payments.legal.address')
    input id="address" type="text" class="form-control" value=entity.address.line1

    .form-inline
        .input-group
            label for="city" = t('payments.legal.city')
            input id="city" type="text" class="form-control" value=entity.address.city
        .input-group
            label for="state" = t('payments.legal.state')
            select id="state" class="form-control" value=entity.address.state
                option value="AL" = 'AL'
                option value="AK" = 'AK'
                option value="AZ" = 'AZ'
                option value="AR" = 'AR'
                option value="CA" = 'CA'
                option value="CO" = 'CO'
                option value="CT" = 'CT'
                option value="DE" = 'DE'
                option value="FL" = 'FL'
                option value="GA" = 'GA'
                option value="HI" = 'HI'
                option value="ID" = 'ID'
                option value="IL" = 'IL'
                option value="IN" = 'IN'
                option value="IA" = 'IA'
                option value="KS" = 'KS'
                option value="KY" = 'KY'
                option value="LA" = 'LA'
                option value="ME" = 'ME'
                option value="MD" = 'MD'
                option value="MA" = 'MA'
                option value="MI" = 'MI'
                option value="MN" = 'MN'
                option value="MS" = 'MS'
                option value="MO" = 'MO'
                option value="MT" = 'MT'
                option value="NE" = 'NE'
                option value="NV" = 'NV'
                option value="NH" = 'NH'
                option value="NJ" = 'NJ'
                option value="NM" = 'NM'
                option value="NY" = 'NY'
                option value="NC" = 'NC'
                option value="ND" = 'ND'
                option value="OH" = 'OH'
                option value="OK" = 'OK'
                option value="OR" = 'OR'
                option value="PA" = 'PA'
                option value="RI" = 'RI'
                option value="SC" = 'SC'
                option value="SD" = 'SD'
                option value="TN" = 'TN'
                option value="TX" = 'TX'
                option value="UT" = 'UT'
                option value="VT" = 'VT'
                option value="VA" = 'VA'
                option value="WA" = 'WA'
                option value="WV" = 'WV'
                option value="WI" = 'WI'
                option value="WY" = 'WY'
        .input-group
            label for="postal_code" = t('payments.legal.postal_code')
            input id="postal_code" type="text" class="form-control" value=entity.address.postal_code

button.btn.btn-primary = t('update')

javascript:
function showBusiness() {
    var legal_type = document.getElementById("type");
    var business_fields = document.getElementById("business-fields");

    if (legal_type.value == 'business')
        business_fields.style.display = 'block';
    else
        business_fields.style.display = 'none';
}
```

And the following controller method:

**stripe_controller.rb**

```
def set_legal_entity
entity = current_user.stripe_entity

# begin
  if current_user.is_driver?
    entity.legal_entity.type = params[:type] || entity.legal_entity.type
    entity.legal_entity.dob.month = params[:dob_month].to_i
    entity.legal_entity.dob.day = params[:dob_day].to_i
    entity.legal_entity.dob.year = params[:dob_year].to_i

    entity.legal_entity.business_name = params[:business_name]
    entity.legal_entity.business_tax_id = params[:business_tax_id]

    entity.legal_entity.address.line1 = params[:address]
    entity.legal_entity.address.city = params[:city]
    entity.legal_entity.address.state = params[:state]
    entity.legal_entity.address.postal_code = params[:postal_code]

    entity.save
  end 
# rescue => e
#   flash[:danger] = e.message
#   Rails.logger.error "#{self.class}: #{e}"
# end
redirect_to dashboard_account_settings_path
end
```

When I submit the form, none of the information is saved for the Stripe entity.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to call `.save` on the account object in order to make the correct API call, not the `legal_entity` subhash. So try calling `current_user.save` instead.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#update_account

Comment: That appears to have fixed part of my issue! Now it's stating my params are nil. :(